# JavaScript in is not giving the property values of string

Tags: javascript

```
    <html>
       <body>

          <script type="text/javascript">
                var aProperty;
                document.write("Navigator Object Properties<br /> ");
                for (aProperty in navigator) {//working fine
                   document.write(aProperty);
                   document.write("<br />");
                }
                var x= new String();
                for (aProperty in x) {//not printing
                   document.write(aProperty);
                   document.write("<br />");
                }

          </script>

          <p>Set the variable to different object and then try...</p>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Here in keyword with navigator object is giving all the properties and printing on console,but why it's not working with string object

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: `navigator` returns the object and you can have object iterated where as `String` isn't  (it's a function)

Comment: `var x= new String(); for (aProperty in x) {console.log(aProperty); }` correctly logs `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` in OSX Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak `String()` is a function, but it returns an `object` when invoked using `new`. It's just that the object has no properties.

Comment: @haxxxton Odd, for me in Chrome it logs `formatUnicorn`, `truncate`, `contains`, `splitOnLast`. In Node 7.5.0 it logs nothing.

Comment: @DanLowe, it logs that for me on SO, however, on a fresh tab i get nothing, and on a site that uses `underscorejs` i get the `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty`.. i guess these site extend the String function

Comment: It probably depends on the iterable property and the JS engine

Comment: @dhaval But new String is an object and "length in x" return true;length is present in string so we are accessing right,so ehy not it's not giving the propertes values